# How to create a single GnuPG signature which works on both LF and CR/LF versions of a file?

Tags: gnupg, newlines

I created a text file using only LF (line feed) at the end of each line. I then made a version of it which was identical, except it had CR/LF (carriage return / line feed) at the end of each line.

Then, using `gpg2` version 2.0.19, I made a detached signature for each file. Each file verified correctly with the correct signature, but failed to do so when I used the wrong signature for each data file.

So far, that's what I'd expect.

But I have in my possession a text file and its detached signature. I now have two versions of the text file, one that's LF style and one that's CR/LF style. The same detached signature works properly on both.

How did the original signer manage to do that? I'd like to be able to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** set the `--textmode` option.

From [RFC 4880, 5.2.4.  Computing Signatures](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.4):

> #### 5.2.4.  Computing Signatures

> All signatures are formed by producing a hash over the signature
> data, and then using the resulting hash in the signature algorithm.

> For binary document signatures (type `0x00`), the document data is
> hashed directly.  For text document signatures (type `0x01`), the
> document is canonicalized by converting line endings to `<CR><LF>`,
> and the resulting data is hashed.

In other words, you need to make sure GnuPG treats the document as a text document while signing, which needs to be enabled using the `--textmode` option:

```
gpg --textmode --detach --sign file
```

By running `gpg --list-packets signature-file`, you will observe the different signature types from RFC 4880, the second line containing `sigclass 0x01` with `--textmode` set instead of `sigclass 0x00` without.

From `man gpg` (it is the same for GnuPG 2):

> **`-t, --textmode`**
> **`--no-textmode`**

> Treat  input  files as text and store them in the OpenPGP canonical text form
> with standard "CRLF" line endings. This also  sets  the  necessary  flags  to
> inform  the  recipient that the encrypted or signed data is text and may need
> its line endings converted back to  whatever  the  local  system  uses.  This
> option is useful when communicating between two platforms that have different
> line ending conventions (UNIX-like  to  Mac,  Mac  to  Windows,  etc).  `--no-textmode` disables this option, and is the default.

> If  `-t`  (but not `--textmode`) is used together with armoring and signing, this
> enables clearsigned messages. This kludge is needed for command-line compati‐bility  with  command-line  versions of PGP; normally you would use `--sign` or
> `--clearsign` to select the type of the signature.